# Access ACF fields within custom preview function?

Tags: custom-field, filters

I'd like to access custom ACF field values from `custom_preview()` filter?

```
add_filter( 'preview_post_link', 'custom_preview' );

function custom_preview() {
    // how to access ACF field values here ?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/preview_post_link/), the `preview_post_link` passes the post object as the second parameter. You can use this to get any fields that you might want:

```
add_filter(
    'preview_post_link',
    function( $preview_link, $post ) {
        $custom_field = get_field( 'custom_field_name', $post );
        
        return $preview_link;
    },
    10,
    2 // MUST be 2 to get the $post parameter.
);
```